# No file was submitted error when trying to do an axios POST between react and django rest frame work

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to simply upload a file in my react front-end and send it to my Django rest framework back-end API but keep getting no file was submitted. I have tried setting the filefield to require=false however this just posts null. I am not sure what I am doing wrong if anyone can help.

model.py

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    file_uploaded = models.FileField(upload_to='Apps')
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.file_uploaded}"
```

serializer.py

```
class UploadSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ('file_uploaded',)
```

views.py

```
class UploadViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Upload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UploadSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
    print(Upload.objects.all())
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        fileSerializer = UploadSerializer(data=request.data)
        if fileSerializer.is_valid():
            fileSerializer.save()
            return Response(fileSerializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(fileSerializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

react upload and submit functions

```
handleUpload = (files) =>{
    var file = new FormData();
    file.append(files.target.files[0].name, files.target.files[0])
    this.setState({mfile_JsonFile: file});
  }

  createApp = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post( "http://127.0.0.1/api/upload/", this.state.mfile_JsonFile).then(() => {alert("posted")});
  };
```

Comment: shouldn't the formdata entry have `file_uploaded` as name, instead of `files.target.files[0].name` ? Otherwise I don't think it can match the serializer field name

Comment: yes that was it thank you so much.